# Forgotten Log-in detials

Tags: lost-bitcoins

I opened an account in 2004 but, after divorce, moving house several times and changing email addresses (with no perfect recollection of which one I used at the time), neglected to access the account and now cannot remember the log-in details - if this is indeed the website I used! how can I access my Bitcoin account?

Comment: Bitcoin account where?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Bitcoin didn't exist in 2004.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_bitcoin  Started November 2008, and even at that time, there were no "accounts" and "websites".  Users had to run their own nodes and miners on their own PC.